# Using entity framework to get info from three connected tables

Tags: entity-framework

I got **products** table

->productID - primary

->price

->Quantity

---

**productCategory** -table

->prodcatID- primary

->prodId - foreign key

->catID - foreign key

---

productlanguages - table

->prodID - foreign key

->langID - forein key

->Title

So I use Entity framework and I shoud somehow get all products WITH THEIR TITLE,QUANTITYI PRICE From GIVEN CATEGORY AND FROM GIVEN LANGUAGE.
SO i should somehow combine info from all these three table

so i made my first function to get all products from given category

```
public List<ProductCategories> GetAllProductsForCategory(int catID)
{
   using (OnlineStoreDBContext db = new OnlineStoreDBContext())
   {
       List<ProductCategories> lst = db.ProuctCategories.Where(x => (x.CategoryID == catID)).ToList();
   }
}
```

So now I have a list with all productID that match this category. But now how to get the data from the other two.

Answer (score 0):

See Loading Related Entities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the material. The problem us that I have read that a long long ago and I know it. And I was asking -  can someone suggest me a way of how to connect to productlanguages table cause I can't find one.

Comment: The answer is in the linked material - the very first section details how to eager load related entities.  You need to `Include()` the additional table:  `db.ProuctCategories.Where(x => (x.CategoryID == catID)).Include(i => i.ProductLanguages).ToList()`.